# /run/user/$UID not created

Tags: ssh, systemd, pam

I have a cluster where users login via `ssh` to the head node. On the head node `/run/user/$UID` directories are created via `pam_systemd.so`, as expected.  Subsequently, users can then log into a compute node, again via `ssh`.  On the compute node, however, `/run/user/$UID` directories are not created (except for one for `root`), although the `systemd-logind` service is running.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

My description of the situation was inaccurate.  In fact the user was not logging into the compute node via `ssh` but using Slurm's `srun` command to start a remote shell. This command allocates resources and performs the authentication via `munge` and apparently sidesteps `PAM`.  If, however, the user just reserves resources via `salloc` and then uses `ssh` to log into the allocated compute node, then `PAM` kicks in and `/run/user/$UID` is created, as expected.